# Javascript breakpoints not working in modal dialog forms using IE 11 on Windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I have an aspx page with an associated javascript file which are loaded using showModalDialog.

If I create a breakpoint in the javascript file, in a function called from onload on the aspx page, when debugging the breakpoint is never hit.

Instead visual studio breaks and shows the line of code making the showModalDialog call.

You can then continue and the form loads but the break point is never hit.

This is happening when using VS 2013 Update 4 with IE 11 in Windows 8.1.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How do I make it stop at the breakpoint like it has done in earlier versions of IE?